# Topology: Continuity , pre images and images.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If we have a function:
$f:X \rightarrow Y$
Where X, Y are topological spaces and f is continuous, then for every open set , $U$ in Y:
$f^{-1}(U)$ is open in X.
(1) If: $A \subset f^{-1}(U)$
Then is $f(A) \subset U$?
(2) If $A = f^{-1}(U)$
Does $f(A) = U$?

My guess is that the first holds however the second one needs an inequality, but i am not able to convince myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with continuity -- really it has to do with the definition of preimage.

If $U \subset Y$, then $f^{-1}(U) = \{x \in X: f(x) \in U\}$. In particular if $A \subset f^{-1}(U)$, then every $a \in A$ has the property that $f(a) \in U$. Hence, $f(A) \subset U$.

The answer to the second question is "no" in general, as functions need not be surjective. Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = 0$. If $U = \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(U) = \mathbb{R}$, but $f(\mathbb{R}) = \{0\}$.